# Workaround for IE8 padding in table causing the border to hide

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm working on making a web application cleanly support IE8 while continuing to support IE6.  There is a know bug in IE8 where the background overlaps and covers the bottom border of a table when padding is used inside the table.

I'm looking for the cleanest workarounds, as leaving the bottom border missing isn't an option on the login screen.

Currently I'm inclined to add an outline to the css, as it is only visible in IE 8, as included below.  I'm wondering if anyone else has a better suggestion.

(I need to admit that I don't have a windows id to check the bug submission with, but I'll probably have to create that from home, as there may be something in there. )

```
table.tblcontentinfo {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, san-serif;
  width: 350px;
/*      outline: 1px solid #336699; */
/* current partial fix  above*/
  border: 1px solid #336699;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

table.tblcontentinfo td {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Html:

```
<body>
<br />
<br clear="all" />
<div style="margin-top: 120px; text-align: center;">
<div id="realpage" style="visibility: hidden; margin-top: 120px; text-align: center;">
<table class="tblcontentinfo">
<form name="l" id="l" method="post" action="check" autocomplete="off" >
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="bgtitle">&nbsp;<span       class="texttableheader">Title</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="125" class="required alignright">Text1&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="text1" type="text" class="formfield" size="22" maxlength="8" tabindex="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="required alignright">Password&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="password1" type="password" class="formfield" size="22" maxlength="8" tabindex="2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<div id="msgpage">
Some text
</div>

</body>
```

(Yes, the clientele is just upgrading now, and at this point we're an IE only shop, although I'd love a browser neutral solution. )

References: 
[# 50 is the bug I'm trying to workaround](http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs)
[IE css support docs (search for outline)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten permission to use the outline hack I have commented out above.  Looks like I'll be checking that in, as the worse it will do is double the border width under a properly functioning browser.

Answer (score 0):

Based off #50 from your link, you should be able to get around that by adding `display: inline-block;` to the CSS for your elements experiencing this issue.

Comment: Isn't that for #54?  I did try adding it and didn't see any effect.

Comment: Using their example for #50 I found that that using an inline-block display made the bottom-border on hover appear correctly, however a visited link with a dotted outline box appears to have an issue after the fact.  I'm afraid when I try setting up your code to see the problem I'm not seeing what it is. (See here: http://www.webdevout.net/test?01C)

Comment: Nice tool.  The CSS should work fine (as that website and every other browser I've tried besides IE8. The issue is actually a bug in IE8, so it's only visible in IE8. Thanks for the time, my boss has said the outline hack is acceptable.